# How to edit content of a tag in a xml file

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

**Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Settings>
  <Tag1>XXXX</Tag1>
  <Tag2>YYYY</Tag2>
  <Tag3>true</Tag3>
  <Tag4>ZZZZ</Tag4>
</Settings>
```

I want to edit only the contents of Tag3 without having to create another .xml file

Comment: And have you tried anything yet? Stack Overflow isn't here to write code for you I'm afraid.

Comment: In my attempts I could only create another .xml file, but this was not the result I wanted

Comment: What do you mean "I could only create another XML file."? Do you mean you want to only replace values at a specific byte position in the XML file? While random access to files is possible, you won't be able to change the length of the data in the field.

Comment: As I do not have much experience manipulating xml file, re-creating another sounds like more practical. However the program that reads this file will see that it will have a different hash and will refuse this new file

Comment: @Sync Surely the hash would be based on the contents of the file and _any_ changes would result in a different hash?

Comment: This particular file allows the user to modify one of their tags. If you change any of the other tags, the program no longer recognizes this file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may edit your XML file like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("D:\\somefile.xml");
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode myNode = root.SelectSingleNode("Settings::Tag3");
myNode.Value = "blabla";
doc.Save("D:\\somefile.xml");
```

Comment: This generated "an invalid token" but opened a range of options, thanks